# Allied telesis 950 series switch , how can i see connected devices' mac adress ? mac adress table

Tags: switch, mac, address

i have Allied telesis 950/48 series switch 
how can i see connected devices' mac adress or mac adress table

Comment: What have you attempted thus far?

Comment: i look user manual it is hasn't any description i try over web interface and telnet but i can't

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be dependent on firmware version. i.e in firmware version AT-S111 V2.0.2 (1.00.016) you can see the MAC addresses under "Bridge/VLAN/Dynamic forwarding table".
Under an earlier version (AT-S109 V1.1.4 [1.00.049]) Dynamic Forwarding Table is not present under the Bridge/VLAN/ menu.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you can't. The GS950 series has a web interface, but strangely the web GUI doesn't provide a MAC table ...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/351627)

Comment: Leave the question open when there's no answer?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Could you clarify?

Comment: Q: "how can I?" A: "you can't, it's not provided"